# Close Parent Window from Button on Modal Window (Kendo UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-window

...So I have code to open a Modal Window on a screen:

```
       var frmUpdateSuccessDiv = $('#frmUpdateSuccess').kendoWindow({
            height: "260px",
            width: "480px",
            title: false,
            modal: true,
            visible: false

        }).data('kendoWindow');

        frmUpdateSuccessDiv.center();
        frmUpdateSuccessDiv.open();
```

On the window is a button with id="uSuccess"

How do I code the jQuery to not only close the modal window, but the parent as well?

```
        $('#uSuccess').click(function () {
            $('#frmUpdateSuccess').closest(".k-window-content").data("kendoWindow").close();
        });
```

Isn't getting it done... and

```
        $('#uSuccess').click(function () {
            window.parent.close();
        });
```

only seems to work in IE (and throws up a big ugly warning that "the button wants to close the window, blah, blah...)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Closing the modal window is `$('#frmUpdateSuccess').data("kendoWindow").close();` (no `closest(".k-window-content")`)

So your button handler should be:

```
    $('#uSuccess').click(function () {
        $('#frmUpdateSuccess').data("kendoWindow").close();
    });
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/BtSUQ/

But closing the window might be as easy as `window.close()` (not sure why you are trying using `parent` unless your code is inside an IFRAME) but in some browsers this will not work for security reasons (disallow web sites from playing with you windows / tabs).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not precisely sure what you are going for given the lack of context to your success window, but this code might get you down the right path. It allows a button on a window to close the containing window.

```
$(".close-button").click(function(){
    // call 'close' method on nearest kendoWindow
    $(this).closest("[data-role=window]").kendoWindow("close");
});
```